# EC2 Volume Attachment Error (Unix)

Tags: mongodb, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, attachment, volume

I am trying to follow the [10gen documentation for standing up MongoDB on an EC2 instance](https://mongodb-documentation.readthedocs.org/en/latest/ecosystem/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-amazon-ec2.html). I am encountering an error when trying to attach the newly created volumes to my instance.

I am trying to run the command

```
$ ec2-attach-volume vol-dac9c92f  -i i-19f359db -d /dev/sdh2
```

The error that I receive is the following

**Client.InvalidParameterValue: Value (/dev/sdh2) for parameter device is invalid. /dev/sdh2 is not a valid EBS device name.**

And the relevant part of the documentation is this

```
$ (i=0; \
> for vol in $(awk '{print $2}' vols.txt); do \
>   i=$((i+1)); \
>   ec2-attach-volume $vol -i i-11eee072 -d /dev/sdh${i}; \
> done)
```

This command executes successfully (notice the absence of the id number)

```
$ ec2-attach-volume vol-dac9c92f  -i i-19f359db -d /dev/sdh
```

If anyone could point out what I may be doing wrong I would be greatly appreciative.

-James

Comment: `sdh2` would be partition #2 on device sdh. you're attaching a volume, which corresponds to an entire storage device, which you can then partition later.

Answer (score 0):

The device that is attached to the instance is mapped to a different device name based on the type of virtualization.

If the instance is PV (paravirtual), then the volumes can be mapped as `/dev/sdXY` where `X` is a device letter and `Y` is a numeric (as used by partitions) - so you can use `/dev/sdh2`.

However, with HVM instances, the `Y` numeric format is not acceptable - it needs to be a volume ID without the partition number naming syntax, i.e. `/dev/sdh`, `/dev/sdi`, etc.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/device_naming.html - see "Recommended values for EBS volumes" column.

*** edit ***
To provide a bash snippet for HVM instances equivalent of:

```
$ (i=0; \
> for vol in $(awk '{print $2}' vols.txt); do \
>   i=$((i+1)); \
>   ec2-attach-volume $vol -i i-11eee072 -d /dev/sdh${i}; \
> done)
```

You can use a letter-based incremental loop (set `volmap` to a set / array of letters `f` through `i` and iterate through the array, instead of just incrementing a counter)

```
$ (volmap=({f..i}); i=0; \
> for vol in $(awk '{print $2}' vols.txt); do \
>   ec2-attach-volume $vol -i i-11eee072 -d /dev/xvd${volmap[i++]}; \
> done)
```

This will attach `/dev/xvdf` through to `/dev/xvdi`. I have used `xvdX` instead of `sdX` so the AWS volume attachment matches the kernel addressing of the devices.